# Convert irregular spaced data to timeseries

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

I have a sales data over a period, I want to convert the data to time-series for time series related analysis. But I am stuck at the very first step, please suggest how to proceed. 
Below is my transaction data, order_date, total_amount and Quantity. My order date is random( not evenly spaced).

```
> sku_top_02
         ord_date total_amount qty
36015  2014-01-02       379.81   1
36022  2014-01-02       610.87   2
36050  2014-01-03       289.17   6
36081  2014-01-03       183.12   1
36128  2014-01-06       303.57  10
36193  2014-01-06        51.65   1
36259  2014-01-07       250.31   1
36222  2014-01-08       408.58   1
36264  2014-01-09       183.40   1
36347  2014-01-09       504.90   1
36323  2014-01-13       529.95   1
36412  2014-01-13       204.96   1
36455  2014-01-14       524.83   5
36504  2014-01-14      3771.41  25
36762  2014-01-20       759.86   2
36794  2014-01-21       539.88   2
36826  2014-01-22       599.34   1
37056  2014-01-22       133.35   3
37076  2014-01-22       174.25   4
...
...
...
Please ignore the first column (rownames, after sorting by order date it is jumbled). Below, I am using xts() to convert the data into time-series.

> ts.sku_02 <- xts(df = sku_top_02[,c('total_amount', 'qty')], order.by = sku_top_02$ord_date)
```

**Something is not working in my conversion**

```
> ts.sku_02
Data:
numeric(0)

Index:
 Date[1:4386], format: "2014-01-02" "2014-01-02" "2014-01-03" "2014-01-03" "2014-01-06" "2014-01-06" "2014-01-07" "2014-01-08" "2014-01-09" "2014-01-09" ...
> dim(ts.sku_02)
NULL
> str(ts.sku_02)
An 'xts' object of zero-width
```

Also, I am not able to plot the TS. Please suggest how to proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `zoo` package for irregular time series. Still, what about observation with equal dates? How would you treat them?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, should I consolidate the data on a weekly/ monthly etc. ? I am looking for some hints on how to convert it to a valid TS dataset.

Comment: It depends on your aim. Yes, you can start from aggregation on a daily basis if it has any sense for your analysis.

Comment: i think using Weekly data will work for you as you have missing data for many days

Comment: Even if you have data occuring in the same week you can aggregate them, maybe using `lubridate::week()` and convert to `date` using `%Y-%U-%d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input data frame shown reproducibly in the Note at the end:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(DF[-1], DF[[1]])
```

giving:

```
> head(x)
           total_amount qty
2014-01-02       379.81   1
2014-01-02       610.87   2
2014-01-03       289.17   6
2014-01-03       183.12   1
2014-01-06       303.57  10
2014-01-06        51.65   1
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ord_date total_amount qty
36015  2014-01-02       379.81   1
36022  2014-01-02       610.87   2
36050  2014-01-03       289.17   6
36081  2014-01-03       183.12   1
36128  2014-01-06       303.57  10
36193  2014-01-06        51.65   1
36259  2014-01-07       250.31   1
36222  2014-01-08       408.58   1
36264  2014-01-09       183.40   1
36347  2014-01-09       504.90   1
36323  2014-01-13       529.95   1
36412  2014-01-13       204.96   1
36455  2014-01-14       524.83   5
36504  2014-01-14      3771.41  25
36762  2014-01-20       759.86   2
36794  2014-01-21       539.88   2
36826  2014-01-22       599.34   1
37056  2014-01-22       133.35   3
37076  2014-01-22       174.25   4"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
DF$ord_date <- as.Date(DF$ord_date)
```

Comment: danke ! (Thank you)  . Your example code helped me, df <- data.table::as.data.table(sku_top_02),  ts.sku_02 <- xts(df[,-1], df[[1]])

Comment: Copy and paste the code in the Note into R and then the code in the body of the answer and you will get the output shown.  There are no errors.  Likely what you mean is that you have tried it on some data that you haven't shown us reproducibly.  See how it is shown in the Note to see how to show data in a reproducible manner.